# How Render json ruby on rails with array result

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

Have:

```
def render
  begin
    array= [:orange => 1,:limon => 3]
  rescue Exception => e
    puts e
  end
end
```

how to return a array in one json

Comment: What alternatives did you check?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def render
  begin
     array= [:orange => 1,:limon => 3]
     render :json => {:array => array},:callback => params[:callback]
  rescue Exception => e
     puts e
  end
end
```